# Merge and sum hash values based off of specific ID and keep remaining hash untouched

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I've tried multiple approaches, including `group_by` and `sum` but because I have two different structured hashes in my array, I am having a tough time solving it.

Here is my data structure:

```
{
DRIVER NAME: [
{
pb_id: "133599.0",
pbbname: "Company 1,
opl_amount: "101.0",
ops_type: "P",
ops_stop_id: 269802,
ops_order_id: 133599,
ops_driver1: 11,
ops_delivered_time: null
},
{
pb_id: "133599.0",
pbbname: "Company 1",
opl_amount: "11.62",
ops_type: "P",
ops_stop_id: 269802,
ops_order_id: 133599,
ops_driver1: 11,
ops_delivered_time: null
},
{
pb_id: "133699.0",
pbbname: "Company 1",
opl_amount: "66.0",
ops_type: "P",
ops_stop_id: 270022,
ops_order_id: 133699,
ops_driver1: 11,
ops_delivered_time: null
},
{
pb_id: "133501.0",
pbbname: "Company 2",
pb_net_rev: "675.0",
ops_driver1: 11,
ops_stop_id: 269587,
dh_first_name: "FIRST NAME",
dh_last_name: "SECOND",
ops_delivered_time: "2021-04-05T13:36:00.000-05:00"
},
]
}
```

I ONLY want to `merge` the `objects` that have the same `pb_id` and that have a `opl_amount` `key`.  If they do not have an `opl_amount` `key`, then they need to remain as they are.  This shouldn't be that hard but again, I am having a tough time executing it.

Comment: What happens if, for a given `pd_id`, there's one with `opl_amount` and an other one without it ?  What's the result of the merging of, let's say, `pbbname: "Company 1` and `pbbname: "Company 2` ?

Comment: There will never be a ````pb_id```` that matches another ````pb_id```` that doesn't have an ````opl_amount````.  Those will always have ````pb_net_rev````, which will get me the necessary revenue for the specific load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that if a group of two or more hashes have the same value of `:pb_id` then:

- they all have the same keys, including a key `:opl_amount`;
- the values of all keys other than `:opl_amount` are equal; and
- they are to be replaced by a single hash with the same keys and values, except for the value of `:opt_amount`, which is to be computed as the sum of the values of `:opl_amount` for each hash in the group (which requires conversions between strings and floats).

One way of doing that is to use the form of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys which are present in both hashes being merged. Those hashes being merged will have a single key, namely, `:pb_id`.

Suppose the given array of hashes is as follows.

```
arr = [
  { pb_id: "133599.0", pbbname: "Company 1", opl_amount: "101.0" },
  { pb_id: "133599.0", pbbname: "Company 1", opl_amount: "11.62" },
  { pb_id: "133699.0", pbbname: "Company 1", opl_amount: "66.0" },
  { pb_id: "133501.0", pbbname: "Company 2" }
]
```

We may then perform the following calculation.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:pb_id]=>g) do |_k,o,n|
    o.merge(opl_amount: (o[:opl_amount].to_f + n[:opl_amount].to_f).to_s)
  end
end.values
  #=> [
  #    {:pb_id=>"133599.0", :pbbname=>"Company 1", :opl_amount=>"112.62"},
  #    {:pb_id=>"133699.0", :pbbname=>"Company 1", :opl_amount=>"66.0"},
  #    {:pb_id=>"133501.0", :pbbname=>"Company 2"}
  #   ]
```

The receiver of `Hash#values` is found to be:

```
{"133599.0"=>{:pb_id=>"133599.0", :pbbname=>"Company 1", :opl_amount=>"112.62"},
 "133699.0"=>{:pb_id=>"133699.0", :pbbname=>"Company 1", :opl_amount=>"66.0"},
 "133501.0"=>{:pb_id=>"133501.0", :pbbname=>"Company 2"}}
```

The block that determines the values of keys present in both hashes being merged is:

```
do |_k,o,n|
  o.merge(opl_amount: (o[:opl_amount].to_f + n[:opl_amount].to_f).to_s)
end
```

As explained in the doc for `update`,

- `_k` is the common key<sup>1</sup>
- `o` is the "old" hash, here the one being constructed, held by the block variable `h`
- `n` is the "new" hash, here `{ g[:pb_id]=>g }` (optionally expressed `g[:pb_id]=>g` when an argument of a method)

Note that the resolution block is *not* called when:

- a hash with a unique value of `:pb_id` is merged into `h` (include those with no key `:opt_amount`) and
- the first hash of a group of hashes with the same value of `:pb_id` is merged into `h`.

<sup>1. When a block variable is not used in the block calculation it is common practice to signal that fact to the reader by naming the variable with a leading underscore, often with an underscore alone (`|_,o,n|`).</sup>

Comment: Wow, this solution rocks ;-)

Comment: Hey Corey!  This is an awesome solution but I do have a quick question.  This is obviously stemming from my RoR ignorance but I keep getting this error - ````undefined method `merge' for #<OpsHeader >````.  I am assuming this is because it's an array of ActiveRecords.  How do I go about converting those correctly?

Comment: Nevermind!  I figured it out and this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Your data seams to be a Ruby Hash but there are some errors in it (`null`, `DRIVER NAME`), so I'll simplify it like this:

```rb
data = [
  { pb_id: "133599.0", opl_amount: "101.0" },
  { pb_id: "133599.0", opl_amount: "11.62" },
  { pb_id: "133699.0", opl_amount: "66.0" },
  { pb_id: "133501.0" },
]
```

Here's a destructive `merge!` function for your `pb`s:

```rb
def merge! data
  # group (by pb_id) the pbs (their index) that have opl_amount
  g = data.each_with_object({}).with_index do |(h,o),i|
    if h[:opl_amount]
      id = h[:pb_id]
      o[id] = [] unless o[id]
      o[id] << i
    end
  end
  # sum opl_amounts into the first pb of each group and annihilate the other pbs
  g.values.each do |a|
    next if a.count < 2
    first, *rest = a
    data[first][:opl_amount] = a.sum{|i| data[i][:opl_amount].to_f}.to_s
    rest.each { |i| data[i] = nil }
  end
  # delete the `nil` pbs
  data.compact!
end
```

You can use it like this:

```
merge! data
data.inspect
[{:pb_id=>"133599.0", :opl_amount=>"112.62"}, {:pb_id=>"133699.0", :opl_amount=>"66.0"}, {:pb_id=>"133501.0"}]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I'll check this as soon as I can!

Comment: A small point, so small it's barely visible, regarding `if h.dig :opl_amount`. That's of course the same as `if h[:opt_amount]`. You really want to know if `h` has a key `:opt_amount`. I suggest `h.key?(:opt_amount)` reads better. It's also safer in situations where the key is present but may have a value of `nil` or `false`. Also, be wary of `dig`. If you expect a hash `h` to have nested keys `:a` and `:b`, it's better to write `h[:a][:b]` than `h.dig(:a, :b)`, as the former will raise an exception if `h` has no key `:a` (which is what you want), whereas `dig` will merely return `nil`.

Comment: You're right, the use of `dig` is useless here. I wouldn't replace it with `has_key?` though, as a `nil` value would mean 'no value' in this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

> I ONLY want to merge the objects that have the same pb_id and that have a opl_amount key

```
result = {}

hash.each do |driver_name, objects|
  grouped_by_id = objects.group_by { |obj| obj["pb_id"] }.values

  new_objects = grouped_by_id.map do |group|
    has_amt, has_no_amt = group.partition { |obj| obj["opl_amount"] }
    has_amt.reduce(&:merge) + has_no_amt
  end.flatten

  result[driver_name] = new_objects
end
```

I haven't tested it but I think this should work.

1. Group the objects by `pb_id`
2. Loop through the `pb_id` groups. Separate each of them into two groups using `partition`: those which have a `opl_amount` and those which don't.
3. Merge the objects which have an `opl_amount`.
4. Create a list containing this merged object and the non-merged ones.
5. Flatten so all the `pb_id` groups are a single list